# maximizing expectation of exponential of a function

Tags: optimization, expected-value

is $\arg\max_{\theta} \mathrm{E}_{\tau} [e^{-F(\theta + \tau)}]$ = $\arg\min_{\theta} \mathrm{E}_{\tau}[F(\theta + \tau)]$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $e^{-x}$ is convex. So we can apply Jensen's inequality, e.g. $f(E(X))\le E(f(X))$ with $f(x)=e^{-x}$

$$\begin{split}\arg\max_\theta E_\tau \left(e^{-F(\theta+\tau)}\right)&\ge\arg\max_\theta e^{-E_\tau(F(\theta+\tau))}\\
&=\arg\min_\theta E_\tau(F(\theta+\tau))\end{split}$$

Comment: Isn't this a counterexample? $\tau \sim \operatorname{Unif}([0, 1])$,
$$ F(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & : 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ -2 & : 10 \leq x \leq 10.4 \\ 0 & : \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \,. $$
Jensen's inequality shows
$$ e^{-\operatorname{E}_\tau[F(\theta+\tau)]} \leq \operatorname{E}_\tau[e^{-F(\theta+\tau)}] \,, $$
but nothing about the arg min or max with respect to $\theta$.